# 80's cartoon about dragon riders

Tags: story-identification, anime, cartoon

I remember watching VHS tapes at my grandparents' house around 1990-1995 so would guess it was made some time between 1985 and 1992. It may have been an over dubbed Japanese cartoon. I can only remember that it was in pseudo medieval setting with castles but also dragons. I think a pack of 10 dragon riders went to attack a castle or something.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JdrLakTz7Ik - Sectaurs?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYBdZOQYSqU - Dragon Flyz?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dHHXRH3xo54 - Visionaries?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jjx0bYepm5E - Flight of the Dragons?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bi3x277sWw8 - Dragon's Blood?